# Read an excel file in java excluding the first row

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, ireport

I'm trying to automatically create reports from a JasperReport template that uses xlsx files, the method I'm using to read from the excel file is this :

```
String[] columnNames = new String[]{"arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4", "arg5"};
int[] columnIndexes = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
ds = new JRXlsxDataSource(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream("../Book2.xlsx"));
            ds.setColumnNames(columnNames, columnIndexes);
```

But the problem is, the excel file should only contain data and I should manually determine columns, my question is how to read the columns directly from the first row and then input the rest of the file to `JRXlsxDataSource` method (If it isn't excluded then it will generate a type error, expecting `Long` but getting `String` instead) ?
Thank you

UPDATE : I've tried to get first row and then delete it but I can't save the file because POI avoids making modifications to the file :

```
public static void removeRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex) {
    int lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    if (rowIndex >= 0&&rowIndex < lastRowNum) {
        sheet.shiftRows(rowIndex + 1, lastRowNum, -1);
    }
    if (rowIndex == lastRowNum) {
        HSSFRow removingRow = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if(removingRow != null) {
            sheet.removeRow(removingRow);
        }
    }
}

public static String[] getRow(HSSFSheet sheet) {
    String[] values = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        values[i] = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).toString();  
    }
    return values;      
}
```

Comment: Do you know [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/)? You cannot treat xlsx files like txt files, they have a totally different (xml based) structure.

Comment: @deHaar That's why I'm asking, to get an idea about this possibility, if it's possible then problem solved, if it's not then that also means that the problem has been solved and I won't search anymore about how to do it and instead format my data to make it compatible with the template.

Comment: You can manually access all the existing cells in an xlsx file using apache poi, that makes it possible. You may have to apply some conversion in order to make it work with JasperReport, I don't know that framework. You can access xlsx files via `FileInputStream`, but it will consume more memory than other possiblitities (e.g. via `File` object). So in general, *it* is possible, but not necessarily easy.

Comment: My code is already working, the thing is as I've explained, it would be better if I can directly read the columns from the 1st row, then remove it and leave the values to work with. I've tried some methods but the first row doesn't get deleted and I get conflicted types error

Comment: OK, show the code that isn't working, please.

Comment: @deHaar I've removed the other parts of the code that aren't working, I'm trying now to create 2 methods : One to get the 1st row and the other one to delete it, if it doesn't work again I'll comment the code I'm using

Comment: Good, but please edit your question instead of putting the code as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Done, don't mind the for loop, it's just because I know that I have 5 columns and I don't want to complicate stuffs for now

Comment: Does this work? You are using a `HSSFWorkbook` but you have an xlsx file which, I think, needs to be read into an `XSSFWorkbook`. Same for `XSSFSheet` instead of just `Sheet` and `XSSFRow` instead of `Row`. Why do you always `getCell(0)`? That will give you the first cell in the row in every iteration. Additionally, you could use `cell.getStringCellValue()` instead of `cell.toString()`.

Comment: Yes, I have both files but I'm using `HSSFWorkbook` in this case
and that `getCell(0)` is a mistake of my part, it should be `getCell(i)`

Comment: What is not working at the moment?

Comment: @Noblesse i don't have a clear vision what you want but i faced issue something like (If it isn't excluded then it will generate a type error, expecting Long but getting String instead) what i did i used dynamic jasper set column type Object. some think like    AbstractColumn djColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setColumnProperty(
            "name", Object.class).setTitle(
                title).setWidth(
                width).build(); set Datatype Object.class will solved my Problem.

Comment: @deHaar I need to make changes on the excel file itself

Comment: @SHAHAKASH thanks a lot for this solution, I didn't even thought about it, I'll try it

Comment: @Noblesse welcome.